# Jupyter Notebook requires javascript. Accesing from remote server machine using Putty.

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, putty

I am new to Linux, and I want to run my python scripts using Jupyter Notebook from remote machine using Putty.  I have set environment variables for Anaconda.

After successful login I enter the command

`$ export PATH="/share/apps/packages/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"`

and

`$ jupyter notebook`

It displays the following window and a message "Jupyter Notebook requires Javascript. Please enable it to proceed".

[image]

My question is how to enable javascript and run scripts on notebook.

Comment: It is better toproxy jupyter's port to your local machine (you can use ssh port forwarding) and use your favorite browser

Comment: I did that still encountered this screen

Comment: --no-browser argument solved it, though

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this will resolve it:

First map the port (8888 on remote to 8000 on local :coz u might be running jupter on your local machine too so good to map. Also if port is already taken you may choose another port) while doing ssh as:

```
ssh -L 8000:localhost:8888 <<user name>>@<<ip of remote machine>>
```

now after activating your conda environment (if that is where you want to work), run jupyter notebook via these parameters:

```
jupyter notebook --ip=127.0.0.1 --port=8888 --no-browser
```

This will print which url you should use, which will be something like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=<<token, i,.e, bunch of numbers>>
```

Copy the above, and change port from 8888 to 8000 (or whatever you have mapped it to), and paste it in browser on your local machine. You should be able to see your jupyter notebook now in your local browser. cheers.